# HTML tables page layout

Tags: html, html-table

[image: picture example]

I am a beginner with HTML and I am trying to make a table layout. So far I have done the table rows, height, data etc. What I cant figure out is something like the six squares up on top (home, about me, product etc.) from the pictures. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
<head>

<title>WEB PAGE TITLE GOES HERE</title>

</head>

<body style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; font-family: 'Trebuchet   MS',verdana;">

<table width="100%" style="height: 100%;" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" border="0">
<tr>

<!-- ============ HEADER SECTION ============== -->
<td colspan="3" style="height: 100px;" bgcolor="#777d6a"><h1>Website Logo</h1></td></tr>




<tr>
<!-- ============ LEFT COLUMN (MENU) ============== -->
<td width="20%" valign="top" bgcolor="#999f8e">
<a href="#">Menu link</a><br>
<a href="#">Menu link</a><br>
<a href="#">Menu link</a><br>
<a href="#">Menu link</a><br>
<a href="#">Menu link</a>
</td>

<!-- ============ MIDDLE COLUMN (CONTENT) ============== -->
<td width="55%" valign="top" bgcolor="#d2d8c7">



</td>

<td width="25%" valign="top" bgcolor="#999f8e">&nbsp;</td>

</tr>

<!-- ============ FOOTER SECTION ============== -->
<tr><td colspan="3" align="center" height="20" bgcolor="#777d6a">Copyright ©</td></tr>
</table>
</body>

<html>
```

Comment: Welcome on SO Canoli. Can you please add to your question your table HTML code? Others can help you faster.

Comment: Please share your current HTML code.

Comment: I have added my html code. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is how you would literally do what you are trying to accomplish (creating a tabular format of your website).  I'd recommend you spend some time learning [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) though and building a proper navbar and a responsive webpage.  It will serve you better than working on html tables.

```
  <table class="table table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Home</td>
      <td>About Me</td>
      <td>Product</td>
      <td>Services</td>
      <td>Maps</td>
      <td>Contact Me</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">This area will contain the Local Navigation</td>
      <td colspan="2">This area will contain information about me</td>
      <td colspan="2">This area will contain statistics of customer satisfaction</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack.

First of all, I STRONGLY advice you to waste some time and learn [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/), table layouts are old fashionend and they're hard to apply maintenance.

```
table .menu div{
  background: yellow;
  color: blue;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 14.66666666666667%;
  margin: 1%;
  padding: 1px;
  border: solid 4px blue; 
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
}
```

I've developed this [Code Pen](https://codepen.io/xjeeh/pen/mWpMGx) showing how to create that kind of floating elements that you're seeking, but I've used some css styles (and I advice you to learn it too, It's extremely important nowadays).

Call me inbox if you want some tips or links to study :)

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick for the menu nav in a flexible layout.

HTML File:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Menu Demo</title>
    <link rel="Stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <nav>
            <span class=menu_item>Home</span>
            <span class=menu_item>About me</span>
            <span class=menu_item>Product</span>
            <span class=menu_item>Services</span>
            <span class=menu_item>Maps</span>
            <span class=menu_item>Contact me</span>
        </nav>  
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS File:

```
body
{
    font-size: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

nav
{
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
    background-color: cyan;
    padding: 0 10px 30px 0;
}


.menu_item
{
    font-size: 1em;
    border: 3px solid blue;
    color: blue;
    margin: 3px;
    min-height: 2.5em;
    width: 14%;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: underline;
    background-color: yellow;
}

#container
{
}
```

~Pat